# Reading RDF does not work

Tags: java, rdf, apache-jena, foaf

I am trying to road a foaf file:

```
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

public class Testbed {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

        try {
                model.read("http://www.csail.mit.edu/~lkagal/foaf", "RDF/XML"); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

> org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 1, col: 50] White spaces
>   are required between publicId and systemId.

I do not understand what this exception means. How can I fix it. Am I using the wrong format (does not look like "TURTLE" or any other format)?

My environment (Windows 10 x64, apache-jena-3.1.1):

> java version "1.8.0_112" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_112-b15) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode

Comment: Your code works just fine on my machine. Are you sure about your error, since the file at the given URL doesn't have a 1:50 character.

Comment: Tested it on two different computers with the same error.

Comment: Could it be that this is an error in one for the referenced files?

Comment: I can reproduce your issue with jena 3.1.1,but it works well with jena 3.1.0. So immediate workaround could be to downgrade Apache Jena (if it's possible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL `http://www.csail.mit.edu/~lkagal/foaf` is actually redirecting to `http://people.csail.mit.edu/lkagal/foaf`. The presence of a redirect is the cause of the error.

The problem was already reported and fixed in the development branch of `Jena` (bug [[JENA-1263]](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1263)).

### Analysis

[Apache Jena](https://jena.apache.org/) uses [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) for connection handling. In particular, `Jena 3.1.0` uses `HttpClient 4.2.6` which was updated to `HttpClient 4.5.2` in `Jena 3.1.1`.

As [@potame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124704/reading-rdf-does-not-work#comment69807217_41124704) pointed out, the issue is not present using `Jena 3.1.0`, the reason is that it creates a connection which by default supports various features, including automatically following redirects (it uses `new SystemDefaultHttpClient()`).

On the contrary, with the update of `HttpClient`, in `Jena 3.1.1` the code was modified to create a more minimal type of connection that is unable to follow redirects (it uses `HttpClients.createMinimal()`).

What happens is that, instead of reaching your `foaf` file, it just retrieves the redirect message which is:

```
name="[xml]",ch=DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://people.csail.mit.edu/lkagal/foaf">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at www.csail.mit.edu Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

and then tries to parse it with [Apache Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/) which is actually the one that throws the exception (you can see that by using `ex.printStackTrace()` instead of `System.out.println(ex.toString())`):

```
...
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:282)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1467)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.scanExternalID(XMLScanner.java:1001)
...
```

### Solutions

- use the direct URL, `http://people.csail.mit.edu/lkagal/foaf`
- use a previous version of `Jena`
- use the development branch of `Jena`
- provide `Jena` with your own "redirect capable" connection, to be used instead of the default one; you can do so calling the method `HttpOp.setDefaultHttpClient` prior to use `model.read`, for example:

  ```
  HttpOp.setDefaultHttpClient(HttpClientBuilder.create().build());
  ```